# dynamically execute a function after requiring filling one textfield and while filling another one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic, textfield

let´s suppose we have a textfield firstname and a textfield surname.

After filling the firstname,while i start writing the surname a function sug()
making suggestions or whatever will be executed and repeated each time i write an additional letter in the textfield surname.

how can we implement this concept using HTML,angular and JS ?
(only the idea,not the function,consider sug() as a mock)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, this could be an approach:

1. a `ngModel` name and one for surname
2. `ngDisabled` while name is empty which disables the surname input text
3. When surname input is enabled, a `ngPress` makes every letter inserted call a function

Here's a jsfiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bnf6cadw/1/